# Database Design related to Categories and Subcategories

Tags: sql, database-design, ms-access-2010, database-schema

I have researched this to no end.  I am not the only person who has asked this question... but I would like your thoughts regarding the best practice.

I'm trying to design a Database that will track financial transactions.  For the sake of simplicity, each transaction can only have one Category, and each category can only have one Sub-category.

I have a self-referencing table, like this:

```
Table:  Categories
ID, int, primary key
parentID, int, foreign key
description, text
```

Long story short, you end up with data like this:

```
1 Auto [null]
2 Bills [null]
3 Healthcare [null]
4 Maintenance 1
5 Gasoline 1
6 Cell Phone 2
7 Rent 2
8 Prescriptions 3
9 Dentist 3
```

So far, so good.  **Here is my problem**:

I don't know the proper way I'm supposed to relate this all back to my Transactions table.  'Transactions' has a column for 'Category' and 'Subcategory'.  Transaction.ID would be the PK, and Categories.ID would be the FK.

With Transactions related to Categories in the manner specified above, that means any value from Categories could be written to Category or Subcategory...

Is it my responsibility as the programmer to control access to the table via a form?  In other words, is my only option 'programmatically controlling' what goes into the Category and Subcategory columns?

Remember, each Category can only have one Subcategory.  The selected Category should only allow that Category's children...

Am I making sense?

GOOD:  Auto -- Maintenance
BAD:  Healthcare -- Gasoline

Comment: ... why can you only have _one_ sub-category?  Does that mean things like `Auto - Gasoline` would be disallowed?  Or perhaps you mean you only want one nesting level?  `Transactions` should probably only have one column - `category`, that may contain a sub category instead.  Either that, or define a multi-column foreign key.  How are you anticipating loading data?  That program/process has the responsibility to not load bad data in the first place, so put whatever basic protections you need there.

Comment: Did you mean that every subcategory can have only one category?

Comment: At the moment, I'm not too concerned with how deep the hierarchy goes... Each sub-category may only have one Parent.  That part is easy...  My problem is restricting what gets written to the Transactions table.  For example:  If I populate Transactions.Category with "Auto", I should only be able to chose Auto's children when I get to Transactions.SubCategory.

Answer (score 1):

The case you pose is subset of the more general problem of encoding hierarchical data, tree structures, in relational tables.  This case has been studied in great detail ever since relational databases first made the scene in the late 1970s.

In bookkeeping systems in particular, the idea of subcategories and categories comes up, every single time.  Larger scale industrial systems tend to have a four level system, with overall account type (Expenses), Category (Transportation), Subcategory (Automotive), and sub-subcategory (Gasoline).

Your research might be more productive if you used the following search terms: "Tree structure in relational design".  That search yielded the following Wikipedia summary:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_database_model

You can find lots of related questions and answers here in SO.  Search under "nested sets" or "adjancency lists" for a couple of techniques.

Your problem is going to be to simplify the answers you will find down to the case where there are only two levels: category and subcategory.

I think whatever design you choose will want to make the following rule explicit:  Subcategory determines category.  and you will, IMO, want the DBMS to enforce this rule so that no transaction ends up with a subcategory that is inconsistent with its category.

Comment: I think we're on the same page!  Transactions.SubCategory must jive with the correct Parent in the Categories.Table.  Is it my responsibility to code that, or can I enforce it via a relationship?

I can't seem to build a proper relationship....  The best I've done so far is show ALL Categories and SubCategories for Transactions.Categories and Transactions.SubCategories respectively.  In otherwords, I have not found a way to restrict Transaction.Subcategories based on Transaction.Category.

Comment: Enforcing consistency in  the Subcategory/Category relationship is basically a matter ofdata normalization.  A normalized design will store this relationship exactly once.  Look into normalized design.  As far as how the data entry form presents the options to the user, that's a matter of forms design not database design.

Answer (score 0):

So your categorizations are not orthogonal and independent (such as gender and city), but rather hierarchical (such as State and County).

In order to enforce a hierarchical categorizations, use a single categorization table with a ID column as primary key, referenced as a foreign key in the data table, and two descriptive fields Category and Subcategory.

To facilitate data entry you might supply a combo box Category which filters the available subcategories. However the actual foreign key reference is supplied by the selection made in the Subcategory combo box, which must list both fields, Category and Subcategory. It would be usual to concatenate these two fields with a delimiter such as dash (-) or pipe(|).

Comment: A single FK to subcategory would suffice.  The subcategory table could have an FK referencing category.  Thus all transactions that are linked to Gasoline are indirectly linked to Auto.

Comment: @WalterMitty: That presupposes that the Subcategory *description* is always unique. Consider the State & County example; There are many duplicate County names across the 50 states of the USA, so any particular one is only guaranteed to be when combined with the State description.

Comment: It presupposes that subcategories have identity. Entities with no identity are a problem, even if everything else is right.

Comment: @WalterMitty: Of course - I am an evangelist of that design approach. Sometimes it is simpler to regard the Category as simply an attribute of the Subcategory (when the Category has no attributes of its own), which I believe to be true in this case.

Comment: Walter & Pieter:  I will design the table that holds the Categories & SubCategories in any way y'all believe is best...  To better clarify:  My problem is restricting what gets written to the Transactions table. For example, if I populate Transactions.Category record with "Auto", I should only be able to chose Auto's children when I get to Transactions.SubCategory.  Is it my responsibility to code this for the client?  Or, can this relationship be enforced within the DB itself?